# python pandas - groupby using column number/location (for looping)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to loop my dataframe through multiple groupby consecutively and I want to use column number (or was it column location?) as the groupby index ie.

dataframe

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-------------------------
  12    22     13    14
  13    23     15    16
  14    24     17    18
```

My code:

```
for i in range(1:df.shape[1])
    grouped = df.groupby([i-1, i])
    #grouping by col1+col2, col2+col3, etc.
```

Unfortunately it is throwing me Key Error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2690, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 1
```

How do I do pandas groupby using column number?

Comment: Can you explain your problem more? Becasue it seems `groupby` here is not possible use.

Comment: I want to group the dataframe by column (2 columns per loop) and count the occurence of similar pairing of items in those 2 columns. So first loop will be like `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])`, second loop will be `df.groupby(['col2', 'col3'])`. But instead of the column name, I want the column index. Example: first loop: `df.groupby([0,1])`, second loop: `df.groupby([1,2])`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) + some function like `sum`:

```
df = df.rolling(2,axis=1, min_periods=1).sum()
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  12.0  34.0  35.0  27.0
1  13.0  36.0  38.0  31.0
2  14.0  38.0  41.0  35.0
```

But maybe need something like:

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    grouped = df.groupby(df.columns[[i-1, i]].tolist())
```

Comment: I dont want to sum it, I want to group it and count similar pairing of items between 2 columns.

Comment: I edit answer. But need transform positions of columns to columns names. groupby + positions is not implementes yet.

Comment: Thanks, that's the information that I want to know (groupby+position). I am actually translating this from R code.

Comment: Just a question still related to this. How can we check if this functionality (groupby + position) is going to be implemented in next pandas release?

Comment: I think the best is create new thread in [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).